# How do I resolve scheduled task created using DSC can't be started manually?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, dsc

I've tried setting up a scheduled task using DSC (Desired State Configuration) that starts at "creation time" and restarts if it's stopped within 5 minutes using the configuration below...

### 1. Create the DSC-configuration

Save it as tasks.ps1

```
Configuration Tasks {

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName ComputerManagementDsc -ModuleVersion 8.4.0

    Node 'localhost' {
        ScheduledTask 'MyTask' {
            TaskName = 'My Task'
            TaskPath = '\My Scheduled Tasks'
            ActionExecutable = '%ProgramFiles%\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe'
            ActionArguments = '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass %ProgramData%\MyTasks\MyTask.ps1 -Param1 a -Param2 b'
            ActionWorkingPath = '%ProgramData%\MyTasks\'
            ScheduleType = 'Once'
            ExecutionTimeLimit = '00:00:00'
            MultipleInstances = 'IgnoreNew'
            RestartCount = 2
            RepeatInterval = '00:05:00'
            RepetitionDuration = 'Indefinitely'
            ExecuteAsCredential = $TaskCredential
            Ensure = 'Present'
        }
    }
    
}
```

### 2. Create an example script

```
mkdir $env:ProgramData\MyTasks

@'
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
  $Param1,
  $Param2
)

Sleep -Seconds 120

Get-Process
'@ | Out-File $env:ProgramData\MyTasks\MyTask.ps1 -Encoding utf8
```

### 3. Prepare the prerequisites

```
New-LocalUser `
  -Name TaskEngine `
  -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString 'mypassword!1' -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Configure the account with the ntrights `Logon as batch job` (should preferably be part of the DSC of course, but I'm leaving it out as to simplify the DSC example)

[image: Logon as batch job]

### 4. Create the MOF

```
Install-Module ComputerManagementDsc -RequiredVersion 8.4.0

$TaskCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential(
  'TaskEngine', 
  (ConvertTo-SecureString 'mypassword!1' -AsPlainText -Force)
)


$ConfigurationStructure = @{
  AllNodes = @(
   @{
      NodeName = 'localhost'
      PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword = $true
    }
  )
}

. .\Tasks.ps1

tasks -ConfigurationData $ConfigurationStructure
```

### 5. Apply the MOF

```
Start-DscConfiguration -Path .\Tasks\ -Verbose -Wait
```

### 6. Inspect the result in Task Scheduler

The scheduled task is created an runs correctly but

- It has the `Last Run Result` set to 0x800710e0 a while in, during the execution
  `The operator or administrator has refused the request`
  This can be replicated by setting up the task manually in `Task Scheduler`
- It can't be started manually
  `The user account does not have the permission to run this task`
- Exporting it when running crashes the MMC
  (this is probably normal behavior)

Edit: Changes in accordance with Doug's comment
Edit: Changed the question

Comment: The order in which you posted things makes it appear you are granting rights prior to creating the user. Also, are you sure your credential is going to be available inside your DSC script? Should it not be passed in with the configuration or another way?

Comment: @DougMaurer Great point about the order in the question. I'll update. And there should of course be a section about ntrights within DSC, but I skipped that :)